# Calculate center point of hexagons starting if we know ceter point of hexagon at center.

Tags: geometry

I am using D3JS to draw a hexagon grid. I want to start drawing grid from center. I have center point. from where I want to start grid.

Example

https://jsbin.com/dehojegizi/edit?js,output

I want to fill up the gaps between hexagons. I want formula to calculate exact center points of hexagons starting from 1st circular grid, 2nd circular grid and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to draw the regular hexagon grid, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_lattice?

Comment: I have first regular grid which I have drawn. Now I want to draw a circular grid inside hexagon. it should start from center